# Object-Equals to force same type at runtime

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering whether it is possible to add something like Objects.equals() that allows runtime checking of types.
Note: I know, that is not what you always want to do, but I think it has its use cases. At least for me.

Example problem: I have some class, let's say, an id of type Integer. And I have an entity Foo with `foo.getId()` returns a type Integer. For some reasons I check for equality with `Objects.equals(someId, foo.getId())`.
Now I refactor my entity, `foo.getId()` will no longer return an Integer but will return Long. Unfortunatelly, there will be no compile time hint at all that `Objects.equals(someId, foo.getId())` will never return true. (Yes, stuff like sonarqube helps you a bit).

To solve that, I thought I write something like

```
private static <T> boolean equals(T object1, T object2) {
    return Objects.equals(object1, object2);
}
```

which.....just does not work. It still accepts any arbitrary Object. Is there any possible solution in Java for this?

Edit: Please note, this question has nothing to do with equals and hashCode of an object or overriding equals of an object in general, I am looking for a compile-time solution.

Comment: I don't know about compile error or code solutions, but Eclipse for example has an option for Errors/Warnings called "Unlikely argument type for method equals()" where you can configure if it should ignore, inform or even show an error for that Problem. For example, when activated it will display the Error `"Unlikely argument type for equals(): Long seems to be unrelated to Integer"` for `Objects.equals(Integer.valueOf(1), Long.valueOf(1))`. So maybe whatever IDE you are using has something similar and you can handle it with that.

Comment: Have you considered `instanceof`, `Class#isInstance`, `Class#isAssignableTo`, and comparing the class types via `==`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes my IDEs does that, but compiling still works

Comment: @Rogue that's not compile time, sorry

Comment: @user16320675 yes, that is what I have done so far and it has the drawback you mentioned, I had to write `MyClass<concreteType>.equals`

Comment: @Torben your propsed answer is only very loosely coupled to my question, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no fast solution short of writing a bunch of `equals()` methods. This might be feasible if you have only a limited set of types that you want to use:

```
public class Equals {

    public static boolean equals(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Objects.equals(a, b);
    }

    public static boolean equals(Long a, Long b) {
        return Objects.equals(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println(equals(1, 1L)); doesn't compile
        System.out.println(equals(1, 1));
        System.out.println(equals(1L, 1L));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not what i wanted :D and I will definitely NOT write dozens of equals methods...but it supports my feeling that there just isn't any solution for what I want thus I will accept this. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Just as Thomas already mentioned, I cannot think of a fast solution either.

You have several options, some of which you may have already tried:

- You may use your own `equals` methods, forcing you to pass two arguments of the same type (either both `Integer` or both `Long`). This is [the solution Thomas proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744176/507738).
- You may force a certain type by typecasts:

  ```java
  Objects.equals((Integer) someId, (Integer) foo.getId())
  ```

  The compiler starts whining if you change the type of either of the arguments.
- Apply encapsulation. Create a class `Id`, in which you store the actual value, either as a `Long` or as an `Integer`. Then if you return an *id* anywhere, use the `Id` class for it. The problem with directly using a `Long` or `Integer` is that you expose the internal implementation. And when you change the implementation, you change the interface.

  Whether this option is feasible, depends on your use case.

If you don't want to use a class `Id`, then I suggest you switch to `Long`, and hope you don't ever need an id greater than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Thank you. While encapsulation in general is a good idea it does not help with the problem. It is still an Object and thus viable for the equals-method without any compiler warning.